# Problema con consulta mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una tabla pedidos_detalle donde guardo los items de un pedido global fila x fila (por ejemplo si un pedido tiene producto 1, producto 2, producto 3; un registro de producto 1, luego de producto 2, etc) la cosa es que al momento de mostrarlo solo me arroja 1 registro, pero si elimino esto: `COALESCE(SUM(ped.precio * ped.cantidad),0) AS total` ahy si soluciono mi problema, pero no tengo la cuanto es el subtotal ya que eso depende de la multiplicacion del precio x la cantidad.

```
$query_pedido = "
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(ped.precio * ped.cantidad),0) AS total,ped.id_plato,ped.precio,ped.cantidad,ped.llevar,
pe.id_usuario,pe.id_sucursal,pe.id_mesa,pe.modalidad,pe.costo_delivery,pe.medio_pago
FROM pedidos_detalle ped
LEFT JOIN pedidos pe ON pe.id_pedido = ped.id_pedido
WHERE ped.id_pedido = '123'
";
$bd_pedido = $bd->query($query_pedido);

while ($pedido = $bd_pedido->fetch_assoc()) {
// codigo de <tr></tr> para mostrar la data
}
```

en que estoy fallando ?

Answer (score 1):

Ya entiendo: pretendes que MySQL te proporcione un listado detallado y totalizado en la misma consulta. Pues no puede ser. SQL se basa en el álgebra relacional y únicamente puedes hacer proyecciones, selecciones, totales y agrupamientos. Bueno, y combinaciones `JOIN` de todo tipo, pero esa es otra cuestión.

Si quieres realizar un listado detallado, eso es una operación de selección:

```
SELECT * FROM loquesea;
```

En cambio, si buscas datos agregados de varios registros, ya tendríamos que hacer uso de las funciones de totales: `MAX(), MIN(), AVG(), SUM(), COUNT(), STD(), ...` con una sintaxis así:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(campo) FROM loquesea;
```

Y, si quieres totalizar por diferentes grupos categorizados por un campo en concreto, ya serían agrupamientos, pero fíjate que siempre hay implicada una operación de totales:

```
SELECT campo,COUNT(*) FROM loquesea GROUP BY campo;
```

> Lo que tienes que tener clarísimo es que, en cuanto totalizas usando cualquier función de totales, desparecen los registros individuales. Si los pides, te da el primero que se encuentra, pero uno únicamente por grupo.

La solución a tu problema consiste en evitarlo realizando dos consultas:

- la de selección: en la que todos los registros que te interesen
- la de totales: en la que muestras ese total que calculas con `SUM()`.

Comment: lo que me olvide de poner fue que SUM() esta sumando 2 cantidades del mismo registro (fila) las sumas no tienen nada que ver con los demas registros

Comment: Entonces no utilices `SUM()`, utiliza el operador `+` y sumarás campos sin agregar registros. Si necesitas ayuda con esta cuestión, plantea una nueva pregunta, aporta el dataset, phpMyAdmin->exportar, e indica el resultado que esperas para esos datos de muestra. Saludos